# Google Maps API mimic OpenLayers' view.animate() function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I'm making an experiment with map animation. For now, I only use OpenLayers 6. I want to implement Google Maps as well.

The idea is to animate map interactions such as pan and zoom. Those animations need to be of a fixed duration. In OpenLayers, I'm using the handy view method `animate()` that way (variables can change depending on the context):

```
map.getView().animate({
  center: [newx, newy],
  zoom: newzoom,
  easing: oleasing,
  duration: durationms
})
```

I was wondering if there was any Google Maps equivalent. For now, I'm only looking for a way to animate a pan or a zoom with a fixed duration value.
I know there are the Maps methods `panTo()` and `setZoom()` but I cannot set a specific duration.

Comment: No, there is no way to add a duration. If there was, it would be in the docs.

Comment: `moveCamera` works without animation, so you could program your own animation sequence using JavaScript timeouts (or even synchronize your Google map with the `change:center` and `change:resolution` events of a hidden OpenLayers map)

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it would either be clunky or I would need to throw way too much events for my liking.

Comment: OpenLayers view animation added to a Google map https://jsfiddle.net/n9xym528/1/

Comment: That's actually working really smoothly, thanks for taking the time to do that ! You can answer this question and I'll accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moveCamera` works without animation, so you could program your own animation sequence using JavaScript timeouts - or even synchronize your Google map with the `change:center` and `change:resolution` events of a hidden OpenLayers view.

For example https://jsfiddle.net/r7kuge1y/ which applies OpenLayers animation from https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html to a Google map example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map